# PHP on CentOS generating blank page, no errors

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php

My sysadmin setup a virtual server using CentOS, PHP and Apache.
All seems correctly installed: I get the Apache welcome page, I can find PHP using `which php` as well as `yum list installed *php*`.

I can also put a file `testing1.html` in **/var/www/html/** and see html content on a browser.

But when creating a file `testing2.php` containing `<? phpinfo(); ?>` I try to access it via browser and get a blank page.

The Apache log says

```
[23/Oct/2015:09:27:13 -0400] "GET /testing2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 16 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/601.2.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.7"
```

which doesn't really help me figure out what's wrong.

Folder permissions are 755 and file permissions are 644.

Any suggestions on how to begin troubleshooting this?

Comment: Try putting full PHP [tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) in the `testing2.php` file. Also, check the error log, usually found in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Comment: thanks, full PHP tags now work--want to convert your comment to answer so i can choose it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the contents of the test PHP file (`<? phpinfo(); ?>`) I suspect that your `php.ini` doesn't have [short-open-tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled.

To fix this, you have two options.

1. Change the contents of your code to:
      `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
2. Enable `short-open-tag` in php.ini.

The preferred approach would be the first, in accrodance with PHP:

> PHP also allows for short open tag <​? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the *short_open_tag* `php.ini` configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the **--enable-short-tags** option).